# Understanding OLTP and OLAP

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling

I know what is the meaning of OLAP and OLTP and who is specialized to do what. Currently, I'm just studying data modelling theoretically and I don't know the practicality of the differences.

I wanted some example that would highlight the differences. So I cooked up one (with ChatGPT) and am not able to see if any differences really exist.

Like if I wanted to model an online order, so I have three entities - `Customer, Order, Product`.

In `transactional database`, I would have these tables and columns

```
Customer - {CustomerID, CustomerName}
Order - {CustomerID, OrderID}
Order_Details - {OrderID, ProductID, Location}
Product - {ProductID, Name, Category}
```

In `analytical database`, I would have these tables and columns

```
Customer - {CustomerID, CustomerName}
Order - {OrderID, CustomerID, ProductID, Location}
Product - {ProductID, Name, Category}
```

The only difference I see is that transactional database has one more table due to normalization. If possible can someone tell what exactly is the benefit. Or if some other example is possible.

Also I would like to know about any differences in ER diagrams for both models (except for some naming changes like entities into fact and dimensions), where exactly things change in the ER as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, the main difference between OLAP and OLTP is their focus and purpose. OLTP systems are designed for real-time transaction processing and management, while OLAP systems are designed for complex analysis and reporting tasks.

You cannot discern the difference by the ER diagram.

You cannot look at a diagram model and say: *"oh, that is an OLTP database..."*

**EDIT:** because you asked me a straight question in the comment I'm going to reply to you with a practical real-life example of an OLAP and an OLTP tables:

This is an **OLAP** table:

```
Customer - {CustomerID, CustomerName}
Order - {CustomerID, OrderID}
Order_Details - {OrderID, ProductID, Location}
Product - {ProductID, Name, Category}
```

and this is an **OLTP** table:

```
Customer - {CustomerID, CustomerName}
Order - {CustomerID, OrderID}
Order_Details - {OrderID, ProductID, Location}
Product - {ProductID, Name, Category}
```

Can you spot the difference?

No, because they are the same.

One is used for OLTP and is receiving 1000 insert per minute.
The other is a simple copy of it, is on another server, is sync immediately or refreshed periodically. It doesn't receive 1000 insert per minutes but Tableau or Power BI connect to it to create dashboards and visualize data.

That's it, they are completely the same.

**EDIT 2**: In [this guide](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-ssas-tabular-model-database-using-dax-functions/) you can see how the same table is used for OLAP and OLTP:

[image]

You can connect to the same database through SSMS if you are working for database administration purpose. But you can also connect to the same database through SSAS if you are working for analysis purpose. And the database stays the same.

SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Service) was developed for shaping the [OLAP Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube):

[image]

So yes, you can use the same database for OLTP and OLAP.

You can also create a different representation of the data with a different table and a different ER diagram.

But that is totally up to you, there are no rules for that. On internet you can find [best practice](https://www.evisions.com/resources/blog/best-practices-for-designing-olap-cubes/) to follow. But with the use of new technologies the idea of the OLAP Cube is also getting older and people start to think of [using the OLTP like it was an OLAP](https://www.holistics.io/blog/the-rise-and-fall-of-the-olap-cube/) thanks to the latest performance improvements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143133/discussion-between-francesco-mantovani-and-dhruv).